# Making heap sort array by struct

Tags: c, heap, heapsort

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h> 

#define maxelements 1000001

typedef struct {
    int key; 
} element;

int maxn=0; 
int minn=0 ;

element maxheap[maxelements];
element minheap[maxelements]; 
element copyheap[maxelements]; 

void insertmaxheap(element item, int *maxn); 
void insertminheap(element item , int *minn); 
element deletemaxheap(int *maxn); 
element deleteminheap(int *minn); 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    double start,end; 
    start= (double)clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int get,num,j ;
    int maxtemp,mintemp;
    element newitem,item;//element to print 
    char arr[8]; 
    char insert[] = "INSERT"; 
    char ascend[] = "ASCEND"; 
    char descend[] = "DESCEND"; 

    if(argc !=2) 
    {
        printf("usage: ./hw2 input_filename"); 
    }   

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1],"r"); 
    // FILE *result = fopen("hw2_result.txt", "w"); 
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("The input file does not exist.\n");
    }
     
    while(!feof(fp)) {
        get = fscanf(fp,"%s %d",arr,&num); 
        if (!strcmp(arr,insert)) { //putting num into maxheap and minheap 
            printf("%d is number to insert\n", num);  
            newitem.key = num ;
            insertmaxheap(newitem, &maxn); 
            insertminheap(newitem, &minn); 
        }
        if (!strcmp(arr,ascend)) {
            //copy minheap to copyheap and then use  
            memcpy(&copyheap, &minheap,sizeof(minheap)); 
            mintemp = minn;
            printf("%d is total number and i will ascend\n", minn); 

            for(j = 0; j < minn; j++) {
                item = deleteminheap(&minn); 
                printf("%d ",item.key);  
            }
            minn = mintemp; 
        }
        printf("\n"); 

        if (!strcmp(arr,descend)) {
            //copy maxheap to copyheap and then use
            memcpy(&copyheap,&maxheap,sizeof(maxheap)); 
            maxtemp = maxn;
            printf("%d is total number and i will descend\n", maxn); 
            for(j = 0; j < maxn; j++) {
                item = deletemaxheap(&maxn); 
                printf("%d ",item.key );
            }

            maxn = maxtemp; 
        }
        printf("\n"); 
    }
    fclose(fp);
    end = (((double)clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("output written to hw2_result.txt.\n"); 
    printf("running time: %1f\n", (end-start)); 
}

void insertmaxheap(element item, int *maxn) {
    int temp; 
    temp = ++(*maxn); 
    while((temp != 1) && (item.key > maxheap[temp/2].key)) {
        maxheap[temp] = maxheap[temp/2]; 
        temp /= 2; 
    }
    maxheap[temp] = item; 
    printf("i put %d in %d and %d \n",item.key, temp,*maxn);  
}

void insertminheap(element item , int *minn) {
    int i; 
    i = ++(*minn);
    while((i != 1) && (item.key < minheap[i/2].key)) {
        minheap[i] = minheap[i/2]; 
        i /= 2; 
    }
    minheap[i] = item;
    printf("i put %d in %d\n", item.key,i);
}

element deletemaxheap(int *maxn) {
    //copy it to copyheap first
    int parent, child; 
    element item,temp;  
    item = copyheap[1]; 
    temp = copyheap[(*maxn)--]; 
    parent = 1;
    child = 2;  
    while(child <= *maxn) {
        if((child < *maxn) && (copyheap[child].key < copyheap[child+1].key)) child++;
        if(temp.key >= copyheap[child].key) break;
        copyheap[parent] = copyheap[child]; 
        parent = child;
        child *= 2;  
    }
    copyheap[parent] = temp; 
    return item; 
}
element deleteminheap(int *minn){
     //copy it to copyheap first
     int parent,child; 
     parent = 1;
     child = 2 ;
     element item, temp;
     item = copyheap[1]; 
     temp = copyheap[(*minn)--]; 
     while(child <= *minn){
         if((child < *minn)&&(copyheap[child].key > copyheap[child+1].key)) child++; 
         if(temp.key <= copyheap[child].key) break;
        copyheap[parent] = copyheap[child]; 
        parent = child; 
        child *= 2 ;
    }
    copyheap[parent] = temp;
    return item;
}
```

It is the code I made to get numbers from input file and make max heap , min heap.
The max capacity should be 1000000 at both max heap and min heap. I think I almost
made function to make those two heaps but it doesn't work well. Futhermore I made
one more heap to store max and min heaps before printing out numbers that are stored.
I think it is fine with the code such that

1. It takes command in the input like INSERT, DESCEND, ASCEND
2. It makes copy heap well by using memcpy function.

But I want the result to be printed 1 2 3 4 5 when command is ascend
and 5 4 3 2 1 when command is descend. But here is the problem.

1. At the function "insertmaxheap" the integer temp does not become same with ++(*maxn) even though I wrote temp=++(*maxn)
2. At the function "deleteminheap" it should print all the 5 numbers but it stops at 3 remaining 2 more numbers.[image: it is the result when I run this code]

The sample input file looks like this :

```
INSERT 1
INSERT 2
INSERT 3
INSERT 4
INSERT 5
ASCEND
DESCEND
```

It is my first time to learn c programming
at university but it is hard for me. I have thought about the code for whole 3 days but can not
find clear solution. Due to cor-vid in Korea, I learn through online and I have to friends who can
help me. Sorry for giving too much questions and codes.

Comment: [Please do not post images of text (code, input, output)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy&paste the text to the question, formatted as code blocks. Please make clear what input you use, what output you actually get and what output you would expect instead. Please explain what the problematic functions are supposed to do and what arguments get passed. I don't see an  integer `i` in `insertmaxheap`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*the integer `i` does not become same with `++(*maxn)`*"? What arguments are passed to the function, what value do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: @Bodo oh sorry I meant the integer temp I made in the function "insertmaxheap" is not changing while *maxn is increasing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification or to fix errors in your question, don't use comments for this purpose. Please add all details: What exact values do you pass to `insertmaxheap`? What variable(s) do you check? What value(s) do you get? What do you expect instead? BTW: When no file name has been specified the program should not continue after printing an error message.

Comment: maxn and minn is declared as (int) not (int *), however you are using *int in your functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remade your code to work:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h> 

#define MAX_ELEMENTS 1000001
typedef struct {
     int key; 
}element;
int maxn=0; 
int minn=0 ;
element maxheap[MAX_ELEMENTS];
element minheap[MAX_ELEMENTS]; 
element copyheap[MAX_ELEMENTS];

void insertmaxheap(element item, int *maxn); 
void insertminheap(element item , int *minn); 
element deletemaxheap(int *maxn); 
element deleteminheap(int *minn); 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
     double start,end; 
     start= (double)clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     int get,num,j ;
     int maxtemp,mintemp;
     element newitem,item;//element to print 
     char arr[8]; 
     if(argc !=2) 
     {
         printf("usage: ./hw2 input_filename"); 
     }  
     FILE *fp =fopen(argv[1],"r"); 
    // FILE *result= fopen("hw2_result.txt", "w"); 
     if(fp==NULL){
         printf("The input file does not exist.\n");
     }
     
    
     while(!feof(fp)){
        get= fscanf(fp,"%s %d",arr,&num); 
         if (!strcmp(arr,"INSERT")){//putting num into maxheap and minheap 
         
            printf("%d is number to insert\n", num);  
            newitem.key=num ;
            insertmaxheap(newitem, &maxn); 
            insertminheap(newitem, &minn); 
          }
         if (!strcmp(arr,"ASCEND")){
            //copy minheap to copyheap and then use  
            memcpy(&copyheap, &minheap,sizeof(minheap)); 
            mintemp=minn;
            printf("%d is total number and i will ascend\n", minn); 
            for(j=0; j<mintemp;j++){
                 item=deleteminheap(&minn); 
                 printf("%d ",item.key);  
            }
            printf("\nminn = %i\n", minn);
          }
          printf("\n"); 
         if (!strcmp(arr,"DESCEND")){
             //copy maxheap to copyheap and then use
             memcpy(&copyheap,&maxheap,sizeof(maxheap)); 
             maxtemp=maxn;
             printf("%d is total number and i will descend\n", maxn); 
             for(j=0;j<maxtemp;j++){
                 item= deletemaxheap(&maxn); 
                 printf("%d ",item.key );
             }
             printf("\nmaxn: %d\n", maxn);
          }
          printf("\n"); 
     }
     fclose(fp);
     end=(((double)clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
     printf("output written to hw2_result.txt.\n"); 
     printf("running time: %1f\n", (end-start)); 
}
void insertmaxheap(element item, int *maxn){
     int temp; 
     temp=*maxn; 
     (*maxn)++;
      while((temp!=0)&&(item.key>maxheap[temp/2].key)){
         maxheap[temp]=maxheap[temp/2]; 
         temp/=2; 
      }
      maxheap[temp]=item; 
      printf("i put %d in %d and %d \n",item.key, temp,*maxn);  
}
void insertminheap(element item , int *minn){
     int i; 
     i=*minn;
     ++(*minn);
     while((i!=0)&&(item.key<minheap[i/2].key)){
         minheap[i]=minheap[i/2]; 
         i/=2; 
     }
     minheap[i]=item;
         printf("i put %d in %d\n", item.key,i);
}
element deletemaxheap(int *maxn){
     //copy it to copyheap first
     int parent, child; 
     element item,temp;  
     item=copyheap[0]; 
     temp=copyheap[*maxn]; 
     (*maxn)--;
     parent=0;
     child=1;  
     while(child<=*maxn){
         if((child<*maxn)&&(copyheap[child].key<copyheap[child+1].key))child++;
         if(temp.key>=copyheap[child].key){
             break;
         }
         copyheap[parent]=copyheap[child]; 
         parent=child;
         child*=2;  
     }
     copyheap[parent]=temp; 
     return item; 
}
element deleteminheap(int *minn){
     //copy it to copyheap first
     int parent,child; 
     parent=0;
     child=1 ;
     element item,temp;
     item = copyheap[0]; 
     temp= copyheap[(*minn)-1]; 
     (*minn)--;
     while(child<=*minn){
         if((child<*minn)&&(copyheap[child].key>copyheap[child+1].key))child++; 
         if(temp.key<=copyheap[child].key)break;
         copyheap[parent]=copyheap[child]; 
         parent=child; 
         child*=2 ;
     }
     copyheap[parent]=temp;
     return item;
}
```

I made sure that both arrays start from index 0 instead of 1, that's why variable `tmp` reaches this time 0, not 1.

#### To answer your first question:

variable `tmp` gets divided by two as long as it reaches 0 (1 previously).

#### To answer your second question:

Your sorting algorithm for maxheap really works but for minheap there is an issue. It runs out of memory range (out of `copyheap` array). That's why it didn't print all of the numbers.
I changed your code here and there to make it more visible for me. Hopefully, it will not confuse you.
If you have more questions about this code write them down, I will be glad to answer. I'm student too so i have some experience in correcting other student's messy code so feel free to ask ;D